# How to scroll storyboard preview?

Tags: xcode, storyboard, xcode7

Storyboard has a horizontal scrollbar for you to scroll to view other scenes, but the scrollbar is not present when previewing the storyboard scene.  How do you scroll storyboard preview? (Assuming I am not using magic mouse)

Comment: Did you find how to scroll it?

Comment: No haven't found it.

Answer (score 3):

What about `Shift + Mouse Scroll`? Or if you have Macbook, slide two fingers left or right on trackpad to scroll.

[image: Scroll]

Answer (score 0):

Just press and hold on the edge of the preview.

[image: Xcode storyboard]