# how to scroll tableview or scrollview in storyboard preview

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, xcode-storyboard

I have a static tableview controller in storyboard representing a long form.
I want to see the different localizations of the scene in storyboard **preview**, but I am not able to see the cells whose position exceeds the bounds of the actually chosen iPhone screen.

How do I make the tableview scroll in the preview window?

This question also applies to scrollviews.

(I have found similar questions, like [How to scroll storyboard preview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33714764/how-to-scroll-storyboard-preview) or [How to scroll UITableView in Storyboard editor of Xcode 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19029893/how-to-scroll-uitableview-in-storyboard-editor-of-xcode-5), but none of them matches my specific question. There is one question that might match mine, but it's too vague to know for sure, and has no answers yet: [xcode7 swift storyboard preview not able to scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38233536/xcode7-swift-storyboard-preview-not-able-to-scroll).)

Answer (score 2):

Controls that scroll must be in focus in IB before they will scroll. Click on the `UITableView` or `UIScrollView` and then scroll as you usually would.

Also, you can set the view controller's size to `Freeform` instead of `Inferred` and resize in IB so that everything is viewable.

Comment: These I know. I meant "in storyboard preview". In IB I do have a Freeform tableview controller, and I set its size so that all cells are visible. But in Preview I cannot scroll the tableview - at least, I don't know how.